# Generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting this error when i try to use the code below,

```
link_to params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil) do
      "#{title} #{content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-chevron-#{direction == 'asc' ? 'up': 'down'}") }".html_safe
    end
```

specifically seems to happen when i add params.merge there. What is the real cause and what should i do?

full error message

> Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters! An
>   attacker can inject malicious data into the generated URL, such as
>   changing the host. Whitelist and sanitize passed parameters to be
>   secure.

using Rails version 5.

Comment: Are you using rails 5.0.0?
According to this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413971/rails-5-0-0-beta1-generating-an-url-from-non-sanitized-request-parameters-is-i) this should be fixed now.

Comment: yes i am using verion 5.0 but i am not using the kaminari gem but rather the will_paginate gem.

Comment: have you tried using the newest will_paginate gem?
`bundle update will_paginate` or use it from github in your gemfile

Comment: Im using Rails 5.0.0 and getting this error too.  Mine has nothing to do with any pagination gems---it is related to params.merge.  I have not found any good info on this.  Do you have any hints after dealing with it?

Comment: @hellion, i am not saying it had to do with will_paginate, the problem is when i use params.merge and no i haven't found anything yet. If you do before me, do let me know :)

Answer (score 17):

Just use the normal [strong parameters feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) of Rails to whitelist good params. You don't have to define a method as suggested in the guide, just call `params.permit(...)` wherever you need it, e.g.:

```
link_to "asdf", params.permit(:page, :customer_id).merge(sort: column)
```

Using `params.permit!` allows all params (basically dodges the new security check) and is thus **not recommended**.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody new to rails that hit such thing, it is about doing `params.permit!` ideally after actually validating these params.

I tried to use `smart_lists` gem which appears to not be [rails 5 compatible yet](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing/issues/96). For me it was about looking at the backtrace to see where the freakin params are used so I can permit them.
Again, depending on usage, permitting should be done after proper validation.

Comment: Update: smart_listing is already Rails 5 compatible: http://showcase.sology.eu/smart_listing

Answer (score -1):

Try

```html
link_to params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil).permit! do
      "#{title} #{content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-chevron-#{direction == 'asc' ? 'up': 'down'}") }".html_safe
    end
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Using `permit!` is insecure because it permits whatever the user sends, defeating the point of strong parameters.